# RANK() Formula excluding rows with a certain value in a dummy column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to create a `RANK()` formula that results in the values shown in Column D in the picture below. Column B will be ranked in Column D excluding the rows with a value of `x` in column c.

[image]

`=RANK(C3,C3:C9)`

Obviously additional adjustments needed to this formula. If anyone has a different approach I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use COUNTIFS:

```
=IF(C2="x","",COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$9,">"&B2,$C$2:$C$9,"<>x")+1)
```

[image]